Why the yum repolist cannot refresh/download the metadata cache during the period of "Repodata is over 2 weeks old"
Enviroment: CentOS 7.4 with yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch 
Question:   Why the following yum repolist cannot refresh the metadata cache for so many years with  much more longer time than its defualt metadata_expire？ 

# 
# 
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                                                                                                             repo name                                                                                                         status
!ceph1322                                                                                                           ceph                                                                                                                 122
!epel                                                                                                               ceph                                                                                                              13,237
!zabbix                                                                                                             zabbix                                                                                                                41
repolist: 13,400
# 
# 
# 
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                                                                                                             repo name                                                                                                         status
!ceph1322                                                                                                           ceph                                                                                                                 122
!epel                                                                                                               ceph                                                                                                              13,237
!zabbix                                                                                                             zabbix                                                                                                                41
repolist: 13,400
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 15 May 25  2020 x86_64
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 114 May 26  2020 7
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 May 25  2020 ceph
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 May 25  2020 centos
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 26  2020 ceph1322
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 26  2020 epel
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 26  2020 zabbix
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   36 May 26  2020 timedhosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul  8 11:11 timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos
total 34132
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34943582 May 22  2020 01225822a45c02962fb91ee8eacbbf4939956640aae0fbf9c2b61c3f5656794d-primary.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3074 May 22  2020 repomd.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 May 25  2020 cachecookie
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       31 May 25  2020 gen
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        6 May 25  2020 packages
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel
total 24500
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    89651 Jun 24  2019 d97ad2922a45eb2a5fc007fdd84e7ae4981b257d3b94c3c9f5d7b0dda6baa098-comps-Everything.x86_64.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3375137 Jun 24  2019 eabda555e71ba756172c4dd78b32c9ce1ba759d7ed798d05e2d98e7bd125065b-other.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7079263 Jun 24  2019 a03015cd83fc6c42d0b41a197bd5504184da66787b1bf0cd44ce5b3312531d8e-primary.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12013825 Jun 24  2019 7ddfabd3875d7e02db5f33e403ec73d50417a69da4d0d8ac8dcf336745a21b4e-filelists.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      431 Jun 24  2019 dff09d8780f079208f89cb8736e5237c2ef6de3367ad438b4d7ac88f8c005587-prestodelta.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1001489 Jun 24  2019 bb50f16f63c496bfb39ef72cc6e79569600ec4cfb2624e0b96565e1d090c85fd-updateinfo.xml.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1502824 Jun 24  2019 db1c409bc28dbf5797d01d27bf0768dc52f651d5ae33dfea145e28ec1e4bff88-updateinfo.xml.zck
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     5477 Jun 24  2019 repomd.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        6 May 25  2020 packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 May 26  2020 cachecookie
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      144 May 26  2020 gen
# 
# 
# 
# python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.metadata_expire, width=1)' 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
21600
# 
# 

